# How to convert Bitmap to byte array(byte[])?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bitmap, arrays

I need to convert a Bitmap to byte array(byte[]). Some suggest that using `Bitmap.getRGB656(...)` could solve my problem. How am I going to use that method if it returns nothing? Is the parameter for `byte[]` in that method will hold the byte array of my `Bitmap`? How about the other parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is about the same `Bitmap` class, but the idea will be the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-to-get-rgb-values-of-bitmap-in-android

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, unfortunately, BlackBerry has its own `Bitmap` class, so that answer isn't portable.  Such is "Java ME" software development :(

Comment: Check this out(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117569/convert-bitmap-to-base64-string-in-blackberry/14131938#14131938), much faster conversion of bitmap to byte[].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117569/convert-bitmap-to-base64-string-in-blackberry/14147236#14147236). Thanks to Arhimed.

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 3):

[getRGB565(...)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#getRGB565%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) will solve your problem. You can also try [getARGB(...)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#getRGB565%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). And It is good practice to read the API documentation to get more information regarding any API method. So, read the documentation :).

Comment: how about the size of the byte[]? is it equal to the dimension of the image? thanks.