# android bitmap color from color.xml

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I want to set bitmap color as `src`. But my color isnt displayed, just empty screen. Im trying to do

```
mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.color.grey);
```

If i write `R.drawable.imageName` it displays image, why my color isnt displayed ?

My color is:

```
<resources>
<color name="grey">#696969</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: because a color is not a drawable? what you can do is create a drawable with a rectangle shape filled with your color

Comment: You could refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-to-get-rgb-values-of-bitmap-in-android

Answer (score 3):

As a `Bitmap`:

```
int bitmapWidth = ...
int bitmapHeight = ....
Bitmap mIcon11 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mIcon11.eraseColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

.
Since it is a color, you don't really need a `Bitmap`. You may be better of just loading it as a `Drawable`:

```
Drawable mIcon11 = getResources().getDrawable(R.color.grey);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could refer to this : [how to get RGB values of bitmap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-to-get-rgb-values-of-bitmap-in-android)

or

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/Findcomponentsofcolorofthebitmapatxy.htm

They mention how you could get the bitmap colors