# getRGB throws error when trying to get the color of coordinates of an image

Tags: java, image, rgb, bufferedimage, arcore

I have been searching for ways to get the color of a coordinate (x, y) of an image.

I have an image, `Image depthImage = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getDepthImage();`, and I would like to do that, by giving the coordinates.

My project is an [ARCore project](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/depth/quickstart) (`git clone https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk.git`)

One solution that I found is

```
int clr = depthImage.getRGB(x, y);
int red =   (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
int green = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
int blue =   clr & 0x000000ff;
System.out.println("Red Color value = " + red);
System.out.println("Green Color value = " + green);
System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + blue);
```

but the expression `getRGB` is highlighted in red. There are not any suggested solutions by Android Studio. I tried importing BufferedImage using `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` to use it, but it was not possible even to import it.

I have also found a solution that would look like this:

```
Color mycolor = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
int red = mycolor.getRed();
int green = mycolor.getGreen();
int blue = mycolor.getBlue();
int alpha = mycolor.getAlpha();
```

But the same thing happens. getRGB is not recognized properly.

Do you have any way to deal with this?

### Additional information:

These are my imports:

```java
import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.awt.Image;      //Error: Cannot resolve symbol 'Image'

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction;
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4;
import androidx.test.filters.LargeTest;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import androidx.test.uiautomator.UiDevice;

import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.HelloArActivity;
import com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.R;
import com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar.WrappedAnchor;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
```

And this is my `build.gradle(:app)`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.ar.core.examples.java.helloar"

        // AR Optional apps must declare minSdkVersion >= 14.
        // AR Required apps must declare minSdkVersion >= 24.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"//
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // ARCore (Google Play Services for AR) library.
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.34.0'

    // Obj - a simple Wavefront OBJ file loader
    // https://github.com/javagl/Obj
    implementation 'de.javagl:obj:0.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    //androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'

    implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'

    implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'//
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved it, thanks to these answers: [How to convert android.media.Image to bitmap object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41775968/how-to-convert-android-media-image-to-bitmap-object) and [How do you get the RGB values from a Bitmap on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669501/how-do-you-get-the-rgb-values-from-a-bitmap-on-android)

According to *How to convert android.media.Image to bitmap object?*,

```
Image depthImage = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getDepthImage();
try {
    ByteBuffer buffer = depthImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
    buffer.get(bytes);
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    mActivityTestRule.getActivity().testFinishedMessage(false);
    Thread.sleep(60000);
    assertTrue(false);
}
```

And according to How do you get the RGB values from a Bitmap on Android?,

```
int color = bitmapImage.getPixel(x, y);
int red = Color.red(color);
int green = Color.green(color);
int blue = Color.blue(color);
```